# Inserting into Group_roles table for all rows in Group table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have five groups in `Group` table as `Group1`, `Group2`, `Group3`, `Group4`, `Group5` and whenever a new role added into `Role` table I have to make an entry into `GROUP_ROLES` table as below:

```
declare @gid1 int, @gid2 int,@gid3 int,@gid4 int,@gid5 int,@rid int
select @gid1 = id from Group where name = 'Group1'
select @gid2 = id from Group where name = 'Group2'
select @gid3 = id from Group where name = 'Group3'
select @gid4 = id from Group where name = 'Group4'
select @gid5 = id from Group where name = 'Group5'
select @rid = id from ROLE where name = 'newRole'

if @gid1 is not null and not exists(select * from GROUP_ROLES where group_id = @gid1 and roles_id = @rid)
begin
insert into GROUP_ROLES(group_id, roles_id) values (@gid1, @rid)
insert into GROUP_ROLES(group_id, roles_id) values (@gid2, @rid)
insert into GROUP_ROLES(group_id, roles_id) values (@gid3, @rid)
insert into GROUP_ROLES(group_id, roles_id) values (@gid4, @rid)
insert into GROUP_ROLES(group_id, roles_id) values (@gid5, @rid)
end
```

Right now I kinda have a redundant script. Is there a way to simplify the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not exists
    (SELECT gr.*
     FROM Group.g INNER JOIN GROUP_ROLES gr ON g.id = gr.group_id INNER JOIN ROLE r ON gr.roles_id = r.id
     WHERE r.name = 'newRole' AND g.name IN ('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4', 'Group5'))
begin
INSERT INTO GROUP_ROLES (group_id, roles_id)
    SELECT g.id AS group_id, r.id AS roles_id
    FROM Group g CROSS JOIN ROLE r
    WHERE r.name = 'newRole' AND g.name IN ('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4', 'Group5')
end
```

Basically, you can `INSERT` the results of a `SELECT` query into the table.  So first get the `SELECT` query right so that it returns the five rows that you want and then just add the `INSERT` clause at the beginning.  Note that I gave the columns aliases that matched the destination columns, but that's actually unnecessary.  I did it purely because I find having two `id` columns confusing.

[SQL Server documentation of INSERT with a SELECT subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189872%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

According to [INSERT INTO SELECT to avoid duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2513174/2625983), you could also write

```
INSERT INTO GROUP_ROLES (group_id, roles_id)
    SELECT g.id AS group_id, r.id AS roles_id
    FROM Group g CROSS JOIN ROLE r
    WHERE r.name = 'newRole' AND g.name IN ('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4', 'Group5')
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT gr2.*
         FROM Group.g2 INNER JOIN GROUP_ROLES gr2 ON g2.id = gr2.group_id INNER JOIN ROLE r2 ON gr2.roles_id = r2.id
         WHERE r2.name = 'newRole' AND g2.name IN ('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4', 'Group5')
           AND gr.group_id = gr2.group_id AND gr.roles_id = gr2.roles_id)
```

I don't know that that's better though.

You can avoid the `EXISTS` checks entirely if you put a `UNIQUE` index on `group_id` and `roles_id` in the `GROUP_ROLES` table.  Although you'll want to catch exceptions in that case.

For the obvious reasons, I haven't tested any of this.  You can test the `SELECT` queries pretty easily, and it's not much harder to test the `if not exists` notation.